# Which is asymptotically larger: $\lg(\lg^* n)$ or $ \lg^*(\lg n)$?

Tags: algorithms

This definition is extracted from "Introduction to Algorithm, 2nd Edition".

> **The iterated logarithm function**
>
> We use the notation $\lg^* n$ (read "log star of $n$") to denote the iterated logarithm, which is defined as follows. Let $\lg^{(i)} n$ be as defined above, with $f(n) = \lg n$. Because the logarithm of a nonpositive number is undefined, $\lg^{(i)} n$ is defined only if $\lg^{(i-1)} > 0$. Be sure to distinguish $\lg^{(i)}n$ (the logarithm function applied $i$ times in succession, starting with argument $n$) from $\lg^i n$ (the logarithm of $n$ raised to the $i$-th power). The iterated logarithm function is defined as
>
> $$\lg^* n = \min \{i > 0: \lg^{(i)} n ≤ 1\}$$
>
> The iterated logarithm is a very slowly growing function:
>
> $\lg^* 2 = 1$,
>
> $\lg^* 4 = 2$,
>
> $\lg^* 16 = 3$,
>
> $\lg^* 65536 = 4$,
>
> $\lg^* 265536 = 5$.

First, I don't really understand the definition of $\lg^* n$.  I haven't met set defined like $\min \{i = 0: ... \}$.  What does that mean?

Second, according to the definition of $\lg^* n$, which is asymptotically larger: $\lg(\lg^* n)$ or $\lg^*(\lg n)$?

Comment: Should that be i>0?

Comment: You're right, there's a typo in the version I'm reading.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm), "the iterated logarithm of *n*... is the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to 1." So I believe Matt is right that it should be $i \ge 0$, and $\min\{i \ge 0 : \ldots\}$ simply means $\min\{i : i \ge 0, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @abmlf: I wonder why you just deleted this other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57250 (and furthermore, after having deleted some comment you had made, if I remember correctly). This is odd, but maybe you have an explanation.

Comment: @Didier: Ah, I thought my comment might be a little bit inappropriate and since the question did get any answers, maybe I shouldn't leave it there anymore.  Anyway, thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prefix $\min$ stands for the minimum of a set - here it apparently means the smallest natural number $k$ such that $\lg^k n \le 1$. Note that, by the definition, $\lg^* 2^m = 1+\lg^*m$, so writing $n=2^m$ (for the purpose of comparing asymptotic growth) reduces the two quantities to $\lg(1+\lg^*m)$ on the left versus $\lg^*m$ on the right; obviously the right-hand side grows exponentially faster.
It can be proved by calculating the limit of the quotient of those last two equations (with L'hospital).

Comment: Is it possible to add more explanation why one of these is asymptotically larger? nice answer but not simple for me :)

Answer (score 10):

```
Which is asymptotically larger: lg(lg* n) or lg*(lg n)?
```

I couldn't follow the CLRS definition of $\lg^* n$ so I went to Wikipedia and saw "[lg* n] is the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to 1." When I tried that for the example given in CLRS, it worked as it was supposed to.

Now, I can see that if $\lg^* n = i$ then $\lg^*(\lg n) = i - 1$ since $\lg^*(\lg n)$ is equivalent to another iteration which means we would need one less iteration to get the result less than or equal to 1 (it's even clearer looking at the recursive definition). Thus, if $\lg^* n = i$, then $\lg^*(\lg n) = i - 1$ and $\lg(\lg^* n) = \lg(i)$ so $\lg^*(\lg n)$ is asymptotically larger.