# Stuck at proof that $\lg \lg ^* n = o(\lg^*\lg n) $

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I'm reading CLRS and have came across the following question:

> Which is asymptotically larger: $\lg \lg ^* n$ or $\lg^*\lg n$ ?

---

I understand there is a question which asks for exactly the same thing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/which-is-asymptotically-larger-lg-lg-n-or-lg-lg-n).

However in the "proof" marked as answer, the writer concludes that

> "Obviously $\lg^*m$ grows exponentially faster than $\lg(1 + \lg^*m)$"

but does not formally prove that $\lg^* m = \omega (\lg (1 + \lg^*m))$, i.e.

$$\forall C > 0 ~~~~ \exists n_0 > 0 ~~~~\forall n > n_0 ~~~~ \lg^*m \ge C\lg(1 + \lg^*m) \ge 0$$

so it is not so "obvious" after all.

As such I'd like to come up with a more rigorous proof and below is what I've tried:

---

My proof is as follows:

> Note that by the definition of $\lg^*$, we have
>
> $$lg^*n = \lg^*\lg n + 1$$
>   Taking $\lg$ of both sides,
>   $$\lg \lg^* n = \lg(1 + \lg^*\lg n)$$
>   Since $\lg (1 + x) < x$ for all $x > 0$,
>   $$\lg\lg^* n < \lg^*\lg n$$

So far so good, but the problem is that I have to show that

$$\forall C > 0 ~~~~\exists n_0 > 0 ~~~~\forall n\ge n_0 ~~~~\lg \lg^* n < C \lg^* \lg n$$

which will be an immediate result for all $C \ge 1$ as

$$\lg^* \lg n = 1\cdot \lg^* \lg n \le C\lg^* \lg n$$

but I am stuck as I am unable to think of anything for the interval $0 < C < 1$.

Comment: Are you allowing yourself to use the limit definitions? It seems you want to define "rigor" to be using the "for all $n>n_0$, there exists $c$..." definition of $\omega$ notation

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm trying to use only the CLRS definition, that is the "for all $C > 0$ there exists $n_0 > 0$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ bla bla bla..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that we have
$$
\lg(n) = o(n - 1)
$$
That is, for any $c > 0$, there exists a $N_0$ such that for any $n > N_0$, $\lg(n) < c\cdot (n - 1)$. It can be proved easily.

---

For any $c > 0$, let $M_0$ be a number such that $\lg^*(M_0) = N_0$. We have
$$
\lg (\lg^*(m)) < c\cdot (\lg^*(m) - 1) = c\cdot \lg^*(\lg(m))
$$
for any $m > M_0$ since $\lg^*(m) > \lg^*(M_0) = N_0$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you :)